# How to prove the non convexity of logistic regression?

Tags: linear-regression, logistic-regression

In linear Regression we have the following loss function :-

$$L(x)=\frac1{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n ((a+bx_i)-y_i)\right)^2$$

Hence, we can observe that L(x) is having a convex graph but when we use the same cost for the logistic regression
the equation turns out to be the following :-

$$L_1(x)=\frac1{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (\frac1{1+e^{-(a+bx_i)}}-y_i)\right)^2$$

Here, $y_i\epsilon (0,1)$ as they are the actual outputs in our data set while predicting the class. Now, when we try to plot $L_1(x)$ using $y_i=1$, I am getting the following [loss function plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sqmm.png)

which is not same as the loss function plot of logistic used in Linear regression's which is shown in the following link here
[Logistic regression - Prove That the Cost Function Is Convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582452/logistic-regression-prove-that-the-cost-function-is-convex).

If we are getting the same graph as the hypothesis function of logistic, how can we say that is a non-convex one ?

Comment: You might try deriving the Hessian and showing that it's indefinite. Or you might look for two models for which the average of their losses on a data point is less than the loss of the average of those models on the same data point.

Comment: @ted can you please post the derivation here I am not able to get an idea of how to do it